# Accessing Variable in Loop

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, global-variables, counter

I'm writing a simple python program using a double loop to print out an html page with a unique set of coordinates. I'm getting an error because it cannot recognize the variable where I have (across + node_counter) in the loop. How do I do this so it gets the variable declared at the top?

```
game_counter = 0

across0 = '72,70,97,70,97,61,116,71,97,83,97,75,72,75'
across1 = '143,70,168,70,168,61,187,71,168,83,168,75,143,75'
across2 = '212,70,237,70,237,61,256,71,237,83,237,75,212,75'
across3 = '283, 70, 308, 70, 309, 61, 327, 71, 308, 83, 308, 75, 283, 75'

while game_counter <60:
    text_file.write("<!-- These are the image maps for game " + str(game_counter) + " -->\n\n")
    node_counter = 0

    while node_counter < 15:
        placeholder_string = ""
        placeholder_string += '<area shape="poly" coords = "' + (across + node_counter) + '" href="#"/>\n'
        text_file.write(placeholder_string)
        node_counter += 1
        if node_counter == 15:
            game_counter += 1
```

Comment: You don't need to put a `continue` at the end of a loop to make it go on to the next iteration. That's implicit in the loop itself.

Comment: What's `across` supposed to be in `across + node_counter`? You never defined a variable named `across`.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about - I'm trying to access the across0, across1, etc. declared up top.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `across + node_counter` could be?

Comment: What i mean is, which one do you need? In what order?

Comment: When `node_counter` is 3, are you trying to access `across3`? If so, two things. First, use a list of `across` values instead of numbered variables. Second, declare more than 4 across values for a loop that needs 15 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to iterate over your "across" variables. Maybe you mean something like this instead: `across = ['72...', '143...']`. Then you can iterate over `across` with a `for` loop:

```
for a in across:
    print(a)
```

I'm using `print` as an example for what the `for` loop would look like. Also, if you're using python 2, you would use `print a` instead of `print(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to add `across0`, `across1`, `across2`, and `across3`, not just plain `across`

Also, you don't need those `continue` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add variable `across` to `node_counter`, but you've only defined variables `across0`, `across1`, ...  That's why you're getting the error.

There are a few other errors too

- store the across values in an array of arrays
- change 60 in the outer loop to 4 (better would be length of across)
- changing the inner loop to use the array length is also wise
- change `across` to be indexed using the `game_counter` on your trouble line.
- the `if` line will never be executed, so you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.  Move the game_counter increment outside the inner loop.

This gives the following code

```
across = [[72,70,97,70,97,61,116,71,97,83,97,75,72,75],
    [143,70,168,70,168,61,187,71,168,83,168,75,143,75],
    [212,70,237,70,237,61,256,71,237,83,237,75,212,75],
    [283, 70, 308, 70, 309, 61, 327, 71, 308, 83, 308, 75, 283, 75]]

while game_counter < len(across):
    text_file.write("<!-- These are the image maps for game " + str(game_counter) + " -->\n\n")
    node_counter = 0

    while node_counter < len(across[game_counter]):
        placeholder_string = ""
        placeholder_string += '<area shape="poly" coords = "' + (across[game_counter][node_counter] + node_counter) + '" href="#"/>\n'
        text_file.write(placeholder_string)
        node_counter += 1

    game_counter += 1
```

But you'd probably be better off with for loops, at least for the inner loop:

```
for item in across[game_counter]:
    ...
    ... (item + node_counter) ...
```

Comment: Yup - how is it possible to access across0, across1, and across3 based on what the value of the counter is?